# Inheritance resulting in an unresolved import

Tags: java, inheritance

I wrote a program that is supposed to use a driver program to make a dog speak, but I am running into an error in the DogTest class on line 8, and it says the import Dog cannot be resolved.  How should I resolve this?

```
// ****************************************************************
// Dog.java
//
// A class that holds a dog's name and can make it speak.
//          
// ****************************************************************
public class Dog
{
    protected String name;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor -- store name
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public Dog(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the dog's name
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns a string with the dog's comments
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public String speak()
    {
        return "Woof";
    }

}

// ****************************************************************
// DogTest.java
//
// A simple test class that creates a Dog and makes it speak.
//          
// ****************************************************************

import Dog;

public class DogTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Spike");
        System.out.println(dog.getName() + " says " + dog.speak());

    }
}

public class Labrador extends Dog
{
    private String color; //black, yellow, or chocolate?
    private int breedWeight = 75;

    public Labrador(String name,  String color)
    {
        super(name);
        this.color = color;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Big bark -- overrides speak method in Dog
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public String speak()
    {
        return "WOOF";
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns weight
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public int avgBreedWeight()
    {
        return breedWeight;
    }


}
// ****************************************************************
// Yorkshire.java
//
// A class derived from Dog that holds information about
// a Yorkshire terrier. Overrides Dog speak method.
//          
// ****************************************************************


public class Yorkshire extends Dog
{

    public Yorkshire(String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Small bark -- overrides speak method in Dog
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public String speak()
    {
        return "woof";
    }

}
```

Comment: Get rid of `import Dog;`.  You don't need it.  You need `import` only when you're referring to a class in a different *package* (besides `java.lang`), and all of your classes are in the default package, so no `import` is needed.

Comment: Unless the `Dog` class is inside of a different package, you don't have to import it. Considering I don't see a package statement in the code you provided, I'm guessing this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import the class in the same package.